# Does each and every web request create a new object for a class in php?

Tags: php

eg:
I have a class named DB. Does the number of objects creation depend upon number of web requests for DB class.

Comment: [You should read the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php).

Comment: Each web request typically runs in its own thread, with its own memory and its own objects

Comment: Each time a script(web page) runs, Everything starts from zero. Remember the web is Stateless. Only the `Session` is maintained between executions